# Kirchoff's Loop Rule

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

For
$V_2$
, why is there no current flowing from the positive terminal from $V_2$? In other words, why does $I_3$ win out from the current that would be flowing from $V_2$ if it was the only battery in the circuit?

Also, why is the Kirchoff loop ebcde in this diagram oriented this way? Could we not argue that the loop should be in the direction edcbe given the Kirchoff loop points in the direction of current flow coming out of the positive terminal of the battery and starts where it ends by convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could very well be the current was pointed in the wrong direction. It does not matter, however, because after calculations you will see if your guess for the direct current was correct. If you get a negative sign for your current value, it means that you chose the opposite orientation. Also, the way the loops are oriented is due to the direction of the current. Hence, it is a convention used to find the current values and depends on your initial guess for the current.

Answer (score 0):

The current from $V_2$ is already accounted for by $I_3$.  When you solve the circuit you will find the current coming from the + terminal of  $V_2$ is equal to $-I_3$.  Also, it is possible for a voltage source to be absorbing energy (current flow positive into it).

You can assume current directions when you draw your arrows - if you assumed wrong direction you will just get a negative value when you solve.